# HTTP Request Mobile Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ionic-framework, https

Hey everyone so I have a question, can I have an endpoint api in my Mobile application?

For example I have a server that would do stuff with data and then I would send a post request to my mobile application letting it know new data had came in. How would I go about that? Is that even possible?

My solution I came across was to use firebase api since I remember It has a watcher. So I can easily change some data inside the firebase database by using my server. The mobile application will have the firebase watcher and see that something in the FB database got changed and it will proceed to react to it.

Without using firebase. If I were to send a get request to my server from my mobile application every second(as a watcher) is that bad practice? Or is that pretty much what firebase's watcher is doing?

I know that when you deploy a web application you can have a backend inside the directory. Would mobile applications even allow that?

Is there a simpler way?

**also note**

I'm using Ionic framework so its a javascript framework

And I'm using nodejs/express as my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I were to send a get request to my server from my mobile
>   application every second(as a watcher) is that bad practice? Or is
>   that pretty much what firebase's watcher is doing?

This is a bad practice and that is not what it is doing.

> I know that when you deploy a web application you can have a backend
>   inside the directory. Would mobile applications even allow that?

You can't have easily a backend in your mobile application. You can call it but not having one inside your application.

Using Firebase is the good practise.

If you want to create your own server, you can create also a firebase cloud messaging server.

What you are doing is called push notifications. More infos here : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/push-notification/info